# In system logs, what does it mean by: systemd: Removed slice User Slice of

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

On a RedHat Linux host, we are getting concerned with the behavior of a user, e.g., `USERNAME.IN.CONCERN`. And in the system log file `/var/log/message`, we see records like below.

**Our Question:**

What does this record mean regarding the `USERNAME.IN.CONCERN`?

```
...
Aug 13 07:46:42 HOSTNAME systemd: Removed slice User Slice of USERNAME.IN.CONCERN.
...
```